# Indexing lists in a Pandas dataframe column based on variable length

Tags: pandas, numpy, python-3.7

I've got a column in a Pandas dataframe comprised of variable-length lists and I'm trying to find an efficient way of extracting elements conditional on list length. Consider this minimal reproducible example:

```
t = pd.DataFrame({'a':[['1234','abc','444'],
                       ['5678'],
                       ['2468','def']]})
```

Say I want to extract the 2nd element (where relevant) into a new column, and use NaN otherwise. I was able to get it in a very inefficient way:

```
_ = []
for index,row in t.iterrows():
    if (len(row['a']) > 1): 
        _.append(row['a'][1])
    else:
        _.append(np.nan)
t['element_two'] = _
```

And I gave an attempt using `np.where()`, but I'm not specifying the 'if' argument correctly:

```
np.where(t['a'].str.len() > 1, lambda x: x['a'][1], np.nan)
```

Corrections and tips to other solutions would be greatly appreciated! I'm coming from R where I take vectorization for granted.

I'm on pandas 0.25.3 and numpy 1.18.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str` accesor :

```
n = 2
t['second'] = t['a'].str[n-1]
print(t)
                  a second
0  [1234, abc, 444]    abc
1            [5678]    NaN
2       [2468, def]    def
```

Comment: This is brilliant.

Comment: I'm almost upset by how simple this is. Thanks @ansev

Answer (score 1):

While not incredibly efficient, `apply` is at least clean:

```
t['a'].apply(lambda _: np.nan if len(_)<2 else _[1])
```

Comment: But not as clean as ansev's answer!

Comment: I still appreciate you fixing this one for me. Thanks!